# Git error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0

Tags: git, github

I have the follow log when I push to `github`:

```
Counting objects: 70, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (69/69), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 16.72 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 37), reused 1 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried:

- `git config --global http.postBuffer 2M`
- `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`
- My connection is over `ethernet`.
- I have the problem since 3 day ago.
- My git --version is `"git version 2.4.0"`
- I don't have firewall
- Also, I can't use `SSH`

Comment: Can you copy the entire error including the command you issued? The return error code 52 means `CURLE_GOT_NOTHING (52)

Nothing was returned from the server, and under the circumstances, getting nothing is considered an error. `

Comment: Just for anyone interested, I know this was posted a while ago, but I was able to get past the problem by doubling the suggested postBuffer to 1048576000

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repository.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an HTTPS issue. Using SSH should resolve your problem.